# C# Create array from MatchCollection

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array

i need to create an multidimensional array from this regex result

```
MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(input, @"( +|)\[( +|)PC( +|)\(( +|)name( +|)=" + "\"(.*)\"( +|),( +|)ip( +|)=( +|)\"(.*)\"( +|),( +|)subnet( +|)=( +|)\"(.*)\"( +|),( +|)gateway( +|)=( +|)\"(.*)\"" + @"\)\]");
```

that regex will catch this string

```
[PC(name="PC1", ip="192.168.1.2", subnet="255.255.255.0", gateway="192.168.1.1")]
```

and what i need is create multidimensional array like this

`[0]PC1 -> [0]192.168.1.2, [1]255.255.255.0, [2]192.168.1.1`

i can get each value of matchcollection using for loop but the problem is creating the multidimensional array

i already google it about 2d array but there's no one work.
i found one code but it can't be used by string

```
        int[][] i = new int[2][];
        i[0] = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
        i[1] = new int[2] { 4, 5 };
```

i need 2d array like this
array[0] -> PCName -> [0]IP, [1]Subnet, [2]Gateway

Comment: A `MatchCollection` is a 1-D collection of `Match` objects - what would the second dimension be?

Comment: @DStanley It looks like the second dimension would be capture groups.

Comment: My approach would be to write a class which holds the required information and then write a method that parses the list of matches into a list of those classes.

Comment: the regex will catch string like this [PC(name="PC1", ip="192.168.1.2", subnet="255.255.255.0", gateway="192.168.1.1")] i need to create array like this [0]PC1 -> [0]192.168.1.2, [1]255.255.255.0, [2]192.168.1.1

Comment: @kanamichan I'm not totally sure that the regex is valid for that input.

Comment: `( +|)\[( +|)PC( +|)\(( +|)name( +|)="(.*)"( +|),( +|)ip( +|)=( +|)"(.*)"( +|),( +|)subnet( +|)=( +|)"(.*)"( +|),( +|)gateway( +|)=( +|)"(.*)"\)\]` i just dont know how to create string 2d array

Comment: element `[0]PC1 -> [0]192.168.1.2, [1]255.255.255.0, [2]192.168.1.1` is not valid as array can contain either `PC1` or sub array eg `[0] -> [0]PC1, [1]192.168.1.2, [2]255.255.255.0, [3]192.168.1.1`. it look like you are looking for a key value pair. so are you looking for key value or the sub array option?

Comment: im sorry i was thinking its like stdClass from php, now i realized the way i do is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to create an object[][] from captured values

sample code

```
       string input = "[PC(name=\"PC1\", ip=\"192.168.1.2\", subnet=\"255.255.255.0\", gateway=\"192.168.1.1\")]\n[PC(name=\"PC2\", ip=\"192.168.1.3\", subnet=\"255.255.255.0\", gateway=\"192.168.1.1\")]";

       MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"name=""(.*?)"".*ip=""(.*?)"".*subnet=""(.*?)"".*gateway=""(.*?)""");

       object[][] values = matches.OfType<Match>()
                           .Select(m => new object[] { m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3], m.Groups[4] })
                           .ToArray();
```

result

[image: result]

note that I have also changed the regex to create groups so that the values can be grouped in the match

try the regex here http://regex101.com/r/nM6lK8/2

Comment: thanks, this is what i really search. how to view object like that?

Comment: you can use watch window to view objects while debugging, just put a break point where you want to see the object's value and add your object to watch. I am glad it worked for you. happy coding :)